# React - passing object through props

Tags: reactjs

I am new to React and trying to pass object through attributes but getting following error.

```
Uncaught Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {title}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead or wrap the object using createFragment(object) from the React add-ons. Check the render method of MeetingComponent.
```

Here is my code:

**Main.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import MeetingComponent from '../components/Meeting.jsx';

let meeting = {
  title: 'Some title'
};

class AppComponent extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="index">
                <MeetingComponent dataMeeting={meeting} />
            </div>
    );
  }
}

AppComponent.defaultProps = {};

export default AppComponent;
```

**Meeting.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';

class MeetingComponent extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>{this.props.dataMeeting}</div>
        );
    }
}

MeetingComponent.defaultProps = {};

export default MeetingComponent;
```

How can I solve this? What is the best practice?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The problem is here

```
 <div>{this.props.dataMeeting}</div>
```

You cannot render an object in React, maybe you were trying to do

```
 <div>{this.props.dataMeeting.title}</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to pass properties of an object , it can be done as follows:

`<MeetingComponent {...meeting} />`

To access title of the meeting object inside the Meeting component, you can do it by calling it directly `this.props.title`

You can render it as `<div>{this.props.title}</div>`

Comment: This is the answer I have been looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

i've used this method to pass object through component

```
   let meeting = {
  title: 'Some title'
};

class AppComponent extends React.Component {
    render() {
const jsonData =JSON.stringify(meeting);
        return (
            <div className="index">
                <MeetingComponent dataMeeting={jsonData } />
            </div>
    );
  }
}


class MeetingComponent extends React.Component {
    render() {
const data = JSON.parse(this.props.dataMeeting);
        return (
            <div>{data}</div>
            <div>{data.title}</div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
  static propTypes = {
    pieChartSortSettings: PropTypes.shape({
      type: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
      order: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    }),
  };
```

Here is a example how to pass object in props. You can also checkout methods like: `PropTypes.arrayOf`and `PropTypes.objectOf`(more: https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html)

Answer (score -4):

Best practice is make your props as plain as possible, in your case it may be

```
<MeetingComponent title={ meeting.title } />

class MeetingComponent extends React.Component {
propTypes = {
   title: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired
}
render() {
    return (
        <div>title: { this.props.title }</div>
    );
  }
}
```

And always use propTypes for better warning messages